# Exclude a column when pasting two data files

Tags: bash, paste

I have one file "dat1.txt" which is like:

```
0 5.71159e-01
1 1.92632e-01
2 -4.73603e-01
```

and another file "dat2.txt" which is:

```
0 5.19105e-01
1 2.29702e-01
2 -3.05675e-01
```

to write combine these two files into one I use

```
paste dat1.txt dat2.txt > data.txt
```

But I do not want the 1st column of the 2nd file in the output file. How do I modify the unix command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste  dat1.txt <(cut -d" " -f2- dat2.txt)
```

Using `cut` to remove column 1, and using process substitution to use its output in `paste`

Output:

```
0 5.71159e-01   5.19105e-01
1 1.92632e-01   2.29702e-01
2 -4.73603e-01  -3.05675e-01
```

Answer (score 2):

If your files are in sorted order along column 1, you could try:

```
join dat[12].txt
```

Comment: Thanks... it works too. But I don't know if I can accept both the answers. If I click this one as accepted, then the previous one becomes unaccepted....But this one works too. How do I vote your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this in awk itself,

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR],$2}' data1.txt data2.txt
0 5.71159e-01 5.19105e-01
1 1.92632e-01 2.29702e-01
2 -4.73603e-01 -3.05675e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut` to remove the first column and then pipe to `paste`.

```
 cut -d' ' -f 1 --complement dat2.txt  | paste dat1.txt - > data.txt
```

Note that the `-` in the past ecommand means to read from `stdin` in place of the second file.

If `cut` is broken on OSX, `awk` might work.

```
 awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'  dat2.txt  | paste dat1.txt - > data.txt
```

Comment: It shows the following errors: cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]

Comment: @user3389597, Your errors are not rendering. Also, are you on Unix or OSX?

Comment: @user3389597, I will suggest an alternate solution, but a lot of Unix tools work funny on OSX. You can also try the other answer.

Comment: @user3389597, And now we have an assortment of working solutions for OSX. :)