# Combining many files columnwise, use first column only once

Tags: bash, csv, concatenation

I have to combine a lot of similar csv files to one file. They are stored in many different subdirectories but the single csv files have the same name.

I need to append them columnwise, but I need the first "name" column only once. So I want to keep the first column of the first csv file and remove them from all following. Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977834/exclude-a-column-when-pasting-two-data-files) I tried the following command: Iterating through all the subdirectories while the final file is in the main directory (And is in the beginning a copy of one of the many csv files, so that it already contains the "name" column):

```
for i in */; do paste final_table.csv <(cut -f 2- "$i"single_table.csv) > final_table.csv ; done
```

However it seems like paste does not work when one of the input files is also the output file.
How would I solve this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite with output the file you're reading input from. Instead, mv/rename it to an intermediate name, let your script read from that file, and output to a file with the original name. Remove the input file when complete.

Alternatively, choose an intermediate name for output file, write all input to it, and only after all input was processed, mv/rename output file to the final name.

as intemediate name, appending a temporary file name ending ("extension") could be useful.

Comment: `for i in */; do paste final_table.csv <(cut -f 2- "$i"single_table.csv) > final_table_intermediate.csv; mv final_table_intermediate.csv final_table.csv ; done`
Seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `sponge` utility from the [moreutils package](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is what I always use for this kind of situation:

```
for i in */; do
  paste final_table.csv <(cut -f 2- "$i"single_table.csv) | sponge final_table.csv
done
```

`sponge` quite simply "soaks up" standard in and writes to the filename you give it afterwards. It is written specifically for situations like this, to avoid the need for you to create (and then remember to delete) a temporary file.